# Not being able to capture "CTRL+TAB" keyboard event in Pop-Up mode of the Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, firefox

We have built an application which is being opened in POP-UP browser window. The application simulates Microsoft Word like experience. In a specific case the application captures CTRL+TAB keyboard shortcut event and do some custom handling (basically inserts a tab character in a document).

Below jsfiddle code snippet shows a sample capturing the keyboard event, https://jsfiddle.net/wdnug6t8/

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  const keyName = event.key;
    // do not alert when only Control key is pressed.
  if (keyName === 'Control') {
    return;
  }

  if (event.ctrlKey) {
    alert(`KeyDown: Combination of CTRL + ${keyName}`);
  }
}, false);
```

While I understand that CTRL+TAB keyboard shortcut is reserved with the browser and being used to navigate among the tabs (when multiple tabs are opened), it is also correct that browser does pass CTRL+TAB event to the DOM when only **ONE tab** is opened OR the browser is launched in the **Pop-Up mode**.

Based on the assumption above, we implemented the CTRL+TAB as per the requirement and it worked absolutely fine till the **Firefox version 49.0**. However, from **version 50 and above**, this behavior seems to be broken in variety of computers.

A point to note here that in some computers it is still working as earlier though the machine configurations are same as that of any replicating computers.

I have also noticed that if you enable the ***“Ctrl+Tab cycles through tabs in recently used order”*** checkbox from *“Menu > Options > General > Tabs”* settings, it also allows the keyboard event reaching the DOM. However, we cannot ask our customers to make this change in their computers as other browsers like Chrome, EDGE, etc. are seamlessly supporting this feature.

Comment: Shouldn't you post your requirement to the Mozilla Dev team instead of SO?

Comment: its work on both i check it

Comment: @Teemu, have posted it to mozilla support as well
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1183461 

let me know if there is any other portal for posting issues to Mozilla Dev team